# Computer doesn't boot to BIOS

Tags: boot, bios, ubuntu-12.04

I, first, started my Ubuntu, then it booted up correctly. But then it became unusually laggy, I couldn't even refresh. So I unplugged my power cable to shut it down (and my battery is dead) and turned it on again. But this time, it won't even boot to BIOS. I waited it for a long time, tried all the keys but no effect, just a blank screen. All the other lights and the fan are working. I don't know if this is the place for this thread but I really need some help. Thank you.

Comment: Does it beep? If it's a desktop PC s does it have LEDs on the back of the case? What do you mean by `my battery is dead`?

Comment: No, it doesn't beep. It's an old, 1gb ram laptop. And the battery has been dead for a long time, it doesn't last 10 minutes.

Comment: I think it may a hardware problem then.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that I switched to another power source after asking this question and it worked. Then after a second boot, it's back to the blank screen.